# "Error: Incomplete microdata with schema.org" for Product

Tags: prestashop, schema.org, microdata, prestashop-1.6, google-rich-snippets

I am getting "Warning: Incomplete microdata with schema.org." when validating my Prestashop 1.6 project with the Google Structured Data Testing Tool.

I include all required field for Products (https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/146750?hl=en).

My code:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
<span itemprop="name">{$product->name}</span>
<span itemprop="description">{$product->description}</span>
<img itemprop="image" src="{$link->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite, $cover.id_image, 'large_default')|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" />
<span itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
<meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="EUR" />
<br />
<span itemprop="price">{$product->getPrice(true, $smarty.const.NULL, 2)}</span></span>
</div>
```

And URL to Google Testing Tools: http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.decoracionna.es%2F

What do I need add to everything works properly?

Edit:

I posted the piece of html code of one product

```html
<li class="ajax_block_product col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 last-item-of-mobile-line">
 <div class="product-container" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
 <div class="left-block">
  <div class="product-image-container"> 
   <a class="product_img_link" href="http://www.decoracionna.es/350367-jarron-de-vidrio-frances-botella-grande.html" title="Jarrón de Vidrio Francés - Botella Grande" itemprop="url"> 
    <img class="replace-2x img-responsive" src="http://www.decoracionna.es/1721-home_default/jarron-de-vidrio-frances-botella-grande.jpg" alt="Jarrón de Vidrio Francés - Botella Grande" title="Jarrón de Vidrio Francés - Botella Grande" width="250" height="250" itemprop="image"> 
   </a>
   <div class="content_price" itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer"> 
    <span itemprop="price" class="price product-price"> 23,98 € </span>
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="0">
   </div> 
   <span class="new-box"></span>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="right-block">
  <h5 itemprop="name"> 
  <a class="product-name" href="http://www.decoracionna.es/350367-jarron-de-vidrio-frances-botella-grande.html" title="Jarrón de Vidrio Francés - Botella Grande" itemprop="url"> Jarrón de Vidrio Francés - Botella Grande </a>
  </h5>
  <p class="product-desc" itemprop="description"> Gastos de envío por Pedido: 8.80€</p>
  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" class="content_price"> 
   <span itemprop="price" class="price product-price"> 23,98 € </span>
   <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="0">
  </div>
  <div class="button-container"> 
   <a class="button ajax_add_to_cart_button btn btn-default" href="http://www.decoracionna.es/carro-de-la-compra?add=1&amp;id_product=350367&amp;" rel="nofollow" title="Añadir al carrito" data-id-product="350367"> 
    <span>Añadir al carrito</span> 
   </a> 
   <a itemprop="url" class="button lnk_view btn btn-default" href="http://www.decoracionna.es/350367-jarron-de-vidrio-frances-botella-grande.html" title="Ver">     
    <span>Más</span> 
   </a>
  </div>
  <div class="product-flags"></div> 
  <span itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" class="availability">  
   <span class="available-now">
    <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock">En stock 
   </span> 
  </span>
 </div>
</div>
</li>"
```

Thanks for reply.

Comment: The snippet you included in your question doesn’t give the error. Could you please [edit] it so that the error can be seen by validating this snippet? (Posting a link is not sufficient as the linked page might change.) -- And it would make more sense to post the actual HTML, not the template.

Comment: I see in html code that appear other params like "<link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock">" that I don´t write in my snippet. Is possible that Prestashop 1.6 insert snippet automatically in some option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your usage of Microdata and Schema.org is not wrong. The Google Structured Data Testing Tool is just "complaining" that you did not specify all properties Google Search needs for displaying one of their Rich Snippets.

It seems that the culprit is the last `Offer`:

```html
<span itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">  
  <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock">En stock 
</span>
```

If you remove this or if you add, for example, a `price` property, Google’s SDTT doesn’t warn anymore.

```html
<span itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">  
  <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock">En stock 
  <span itemprop="price">10</span>
</span>
```

If I understand your code correctly, it seems that this `Offer` is about the same offer as the previous `Offer` (where you specify `price`/`priceCurrency`). If that’s the case, you should merge them into one item.

```html
<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer"> 
 <span itemprop="price">23,98</span> € <!-- I removed the currency symbol from the price property, and added the currency to the priceCurrency property -->
 <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="EUR">
 <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock">En stock 
</div>
```

Comment: I modify offers and the Rich Snippets work fine, now I only need find in which part of code duplicate this Snippets. A lot of thanks.